# Chess - iOS - SpriteKit - Human move is not displayed until computer thinking ends

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift2, chess

I am developing an IOS Chess app using SpriteKit in Swift2. While playing the game against computer player, human move is not displayed until computer thinking ends. After computer thinking ends, both (human move and computer move) moves are displayed together.

**Expected functionality**: Once human plays his/her move, the move must be displayed on screen. Only after displaying the human move, computer thinking must start.

I initially had the call to computer thinking logic inside ***touchesBegan*** function. It didn't work as expected. Then I moved the call into ***touchesEnded*** function. The issue remained. Now I have placed the call inside ***update*** function. The issue still remains.

I couldn't find an answer for this issue. Is there any away to address this?

Thanks,
ArtBajji

Comment: SpriteKit provides two sanctioned ways for time related actions. SKAction and update: method with its currentTime passed parameter. Also you can easily implement completion handlers in Swift. With all this you can easily run Computer move after the Player move animation is done. Search SO about how to use SKaction sequence and completion handlers.

Comment: Thanks. As you suggested, using SKAction, Custom queueing implementations and action completion handler I solved this requirement in my app.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that the "computer" reacts to quickly after a human move, you could use a `dispatch_after` block implemented in your `touchesEnded`.

```
let delay = 0     //time in seconds
dispatch_after(delay, dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
    //computer starts thinking 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it is the other way round. The computer thinking takes more than 30 seconds. So until computer thinking ends, the human move played prior to computer thinking is not displayed on the screen. The requirement is to display the human move and then start the computer thinking.